# How can I add a search field on my processing page?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created a custom processing page called "Kardex Process", by default it doesn't add a search field, and I want to include it.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

I want to include it as well as on the Release AP Documents screen, see the screen below:

[image]

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define FastFilterFields property in the grid control and list fields that you want to be included in the search.

```
<px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" ... SkinID="PrimaryInquire"       FastFilterFields="RefNbr,VendorID,VendorID_Vendor_acctName">
```